# Would a [foreign-language] tag be worth creating?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just created a question on [the availability of Dungeons & Dragons in Hungarian](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44603/7373). I had considered creating a [foreign-language] tag for this question and similar (English) questions that discuss roleplaying games in other languages. Is this something that might be worth creating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: Based on Mxy's comment below and my perusal of the tags in question, I've concluded that the [languages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) tag should be used for setting-specific language questions (it's *never* been used for translation questions yet, so far as I can tell, so this requires no re-tagging effort) while questions about real-world languages should be tagged with that specific language. So far we have only one such question: the [hungarian](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hungarian) question which sparked this discussion in the first place.

I've given the [hungarian](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hungarian) tag a rudimentary wiki (someone who knows more should modify it!) and edited the [languages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) tag to say that real-world language questions should get tagged with the specific language.

---

**TL;DR:** I'm not sure [foreign-languages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-languages) is the right tag. I think there should be a tag, but I dunno what it is. See below for rumination and suggestions.

Apparently [it already exists](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-language) but has no content! That means it'll probably get purged some time soon unless it's used.

Let's think about tags a bit: their primary purpose is to help people find answers useful to them, and to help connect experts with questions they can answer.

Many users on our site are not native English speakers, and game in languages other than English, which means questions about languages other than English will be useful to the site and we probably already have experts on the topic... except... an expert on gaming in Hungarian may not be very helpful to a Hebrew-speaking gamer, and neither of them can help the Italian gamer much with his language-related challenges. This tells me [foreign-languages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-languages) is too broad to be a useful tag in most cases, much like the [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) tag should be replaced by edition-specific tags whenever appropriate so we get 3.5 experts looking at 3.5 questions and when I look for answers to my 4e problems I don't have to wade through AD&D questions.

So my instinct is to say that a [hungarian](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hungarian) tag (and [italian](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian), [hebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew), [dutch](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch), etc) would be more useful than a [foreign-languages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-languages) tag.

However, then I look at your question and wonder if a [translation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag would be appropriate (instead or or in addition to a language-specific tag, I'm not sure): it's likely that a person who knows about game translations would know about multiple languages' worth of translated games.

At the end of the day, I think we need to let these tags evolve like they always do: organically, meeting needs as we encounter them rather than anticipating needs we don't yet have. But again, I'm not sure what that looks like in this case.

Comment: Actually, I think the [foreign-language] tag is empty because I created it, then edited the question to remove it and asked the question here on meta. I would like to have a tag grow organically, but I just wanted to know what it should be called. [Translation] sounds like a good name for it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd think the actual languages (e.g. Hungarian) would be the only useful ones.  What help is looking at "all questions about translations into anything?"

Comment: @mxyzplk If suddenly there were a lot of foreign languages questions, English speakers could ignore them with that tag.

Comment: @Flamma That's an excellent point, but we try not to create tags in anticipation of theoretical futures. I'll be very happy if we do wind up needing to create tags for that eventuality, but we need to focus on what's happening now, tagging for situations as they emerge rather than preemptively.

Comment: @Thunderforge I've updated my answer to reflect the comment discussion, and made some tag wiki edits accordingly. You should consider improving the [hungarian] tag, as I don't know enough about it to do the subject justice.

Comment: @BESW, I've made a couple edits to the tag, but I admit that I'm not truly an expert in it. Looks like the tag already had a great start!

Comment: @BESW Agreed. Just wanted to point the possibility.